# Add relationships to non-saved NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

```
NSManagedObject *parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[child setValue:parent forKey:@"parent"];
```

That doesn't seem to work for me, but I can do something like this:

```
[child setValue:"John" forKey:@"name"];
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship has been defined in the `ManagedObjectModel` you can use

```
[parent setValue:child forKey:@"childObject"];
```

This code example assumes that your Entity Parent has a relationship attribute set called childObject.

[image]

To use the . accessor for a property of a `NSManagedObject` you will need to subclass it.
Select your Entity and click Create `NSManagedObject` Subclass from the Editor Menu

[image: EditorMenu]

Then instead of Creating your objects as `NSManagedObjects`, create them as Parent and Child classes

```
#import "Parent.h"
#import "Child" 
Parent *parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
parent.childObj = child;
```

Comment: That's very weird - that's what I'm doing, but it's not saving. It must be something else I'm doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have the relationship destination set to the Child entity in the Core Data?

Comment: I do - I have a One to Many setup between the Parent to Child and Many to One between Child and Parent. Children only have one parent.

Comment: I updated with more information on subclassing NSManaged Object. This should fix the original problem you had with trying to use the dot accessor.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'll just do that. It was really what I was trying to avoid, but I guess I have to sacrifice some simplicity to get through this.